# Android NDK in Android studio 2.0 preview 5 with gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I had a problem when using 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha6' with Android Studio 2.0 preview 5.

Here is my simple project (just hello world):
[https://github.com/nthtrung09it/HelloGradleExperimental][1]

My build.gradle file:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        ndk {
            moduleName "NdkLib"
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "nthtrung09it.android.hello.experimental"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}
```

Here is problem:

> Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task
>   ':app:stripSymbolsArmeabi-v7aDebugArmSharedLibrary'.
>    Directory 'E:\xxxx\HelloGradleExperimental-master\app\build\intermediates\binaries\debug\arm\obj\armeabi-v7a'
>   specified for property 'inputFolder' does not exist.

The **binaries** folder does not exist.
Where is my error? Thanks.

Comment: You are using 2 beta plugins, you should expect errors/bugs.

Comment: @JaredBurrows: correction: *alpha*

Comment: I believe you're aware of this issue in Android studio's bug tracker, but I posted a workaround which you may find helpful: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199057

Comment: Tks for all answers.

Comment: I use a stable version of gradle-experimental (version 0.4.0) with android studio 1.5.1 and build standard alone *.so files then use it in my project (current is Android Studio 2.0 Preview 7, gradle 2.0.0-alpha7).

Comment: Because it is just alpha version of gradle-experimental plugin, we shouldn't waste of time to deal with these errors.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problems. Using newer version of plugin solved it for me -  **'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-beta4'**.

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 though.

EDIT: Now you can use more recent version too: **0.6.0-beta5**

Answer (score 0):

Try to create given folder:

```
$ mkdir E:\xxxx\HelloGradleExperimental-master\app\build\intermediates\binaries\debug\arm\obj\armeabi-v7a
```